# Shell Script question mark (?) issue in its uses

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I am trying to run below script but facing an issue .
I got the solution but still why this solution is working that I Am not clear . 
I want to know the concept behind this :

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# RUN script



echo "please run with: nice nohup ./run_script"

# working directory where script is stored
WORKING_DIR=$(pwd)

# temp directory to build and run the cmake ctest
BUILD_DIR?=/localtemp/build

# clean and make build directory
rm -rf $BUILD_DIR
mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR
mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR/../result
```

Getting error as :

```
BUILD_DIR?=/localtemp/build: No such file or directory
mkdir: missing operand
Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/../result’: Permission denied
```

But if I remove the  "?"  from the line `BUILD_DIR?=/localtemp/build` and making it `BUILD_DIR=/localtemp/build`, the scripts run fine .

**My assumptions:**

I want **"?"** with `BUILD_DIR` line as if some one wants to set the BUILD_DIR from outside the script it has to take the outside path. otherwise by default it has to go with the above path mentioned in my script .

Can anyone clear my doubt in the shell script about the "?" use

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're confusing Makefile syntax with bash syntax.  The expression `?=` isn't a valid bash expression.  You can instead write something like this:

```
BUILD_DIR=${BUILD_DIR:-/localtemp/build}
```

Which means set BUILD_DIR to the value of BUILD_DIR, if it's set, otherwise to `/localtemp/build`.

Comment: Or more DRYly, `: ${BUILD_DIR:=/localtemp/build}`.